# 'Base class' : undeclared identifier (Polymorphism)

Tags: c++, c++14, sfml, smart-pointers

I'm working on a project in which I'm implementing an interface using SFML. So... I've created one base class `SortingAlgorithms`, the subclasses that will inherit from the base class and the `Interface` class which contains the interface implementations.

The project was working before when I had one single header file, but now I've separated the classes in different header files.

So my problem is in the `Algorithms.h` file, where the virtual method `Sort` is.

After compilation I get those errors:

**C2065 'Interface' undeclared identifier**

**C2923 'std::unique_ptr':'Interface' is not valid template for argument '_Ty'**

**unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation**

**Algorithms.h :**

```
#ifndef ALGORITHMS_H_INCLUDED
#define ALGORITHMS_H_INCLUDED


#include "Interface.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <vector>


/* Base class from which the sorting algorithms will inherit (Polymorphic class) */
class SortingAlgorithms
{
protected:
    std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> sequence;
    sf::RenderWindow& window;
    int minimum, maximum;
    int elements;

public:
    SortingAlgorithms();

    // Class constructor which initializes a sequence
    SortingAlgorithms(int min, int max, int els, sf::RenderWindow& win);

    std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> GetSequence() const;

    // A pure virtual function for overriding 
    virtual void Sort(std::unique_ptr<Interface>& init) = 0;

    // A method for printing the sequence
    void Print(std::unique_ptr<Interface>& init);
};






#endif // ALGORITHMS_H_INCLUDED
```

**Interface.h :**

```
#ifndef INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED
#define INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED

#include "Algorithms.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <vector>


/* The Button class will allow us to create a button (a shape with text) */
class Button
{
protected:
    sf::Text text;
    sf::RectangleShape button;
public:
    Button();
    Button(std::string txt, sf::Color txtColor, int txtSize, sf::Color shapeColor, sf::Vector2f shapeSize);

    // Positionate method will set the position on (x, y) axis
    void Positionate(sf::Vector2f size);

    // SetShapeColor, SetTextColor will set the shape colors
    void SetShapeColor(sf::Color color);

    void SetTextColor(sf::Color color);

    // SetFont will set the text font e.g. arial
    void SetFont(sf::Font& font);

    // DetectMouse when hoovering over the button
    bool DetectButton(sf::RenderWindow& window);

    // Returns the text from inside of a button 
    std::string GetButton() const;

    // Changes the string text and repositionate the text
    void SetButton(const std::string& str);

    // Draw draws the button on the screen
    void Draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);
};


/* Class Interface contains the functionlaties of the window */
class Interface
{
protected:
    sf::RenderWindow window;
    sf::Font font;
    sf::Text hint;
    
    /* I'll be using a container for our buttons since we'll have some more */
    Button clrScrB;
    Button generateSeqB;
    Button sortAlgB;
    Button resetConfigB;
    Button increaseMinB;
    Button increaseMaxB;
    Button outputMinB;
    Button outputMaxB;
    Button plusElsB;
    Button minusElsB;
    Button outputElsB;

    int inputMin = 0;
    int inputMax = 0;
    int inputEls = 0;
    
    std::string algorithmType;
    std::string selectedAlg;
    std::shared_ptr<SortingAlgorithms> generateSeq;

    std::vector<Button> menuButtons;
    std::vector<Button> configButtons;
    std::vector<Button> sortingAlgsButtons;
    std::vector<Button> pathAlgsButtons;

public:
    Interface();

    // Initializes the window within the main loop  
    void Init(std::unique_ptr<Interface>& init);

    void SortingAlgMenu(std::unique_ptr<Interface>& init);

    void PathAlgMenu(std::unique_ptr<Interface>& init);

    void ConfigBar(std::unique_ptr<Interface>& init);
};






#endif // INTERFACE_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: Follow your include guard macros. The problem should make itself evident if your head-preprocess `Interface.h` defining guards, then including `Algorithms.h`, which includes `Interface.h` (which becomes a no-op because its guards are already affixed).  I.e. you have a circular include problem, which isn't entirely uncommon, and a worthy search term on this site.

Comment: That's it! Thanks :D